# Pre populate Woocommerce checkout fields

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to pre-populate additional fields in the woocommerce checkout page but I am struggling with it.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_get_value', function($input, $key ) {
    global $current_user;

    switch ($key) :
        case 'billing_first_name':
        case 'shipping_first_name':
            return $current_user->first_name;
        break;
        case 'billing_last_name':
        case 'shipping_last_name':
            return $current_user->last_name;

        case 'billing_phone':
            return $current_user->phone;
        break;
                case 'billing_company':
                case 'shipping_company':
            return $current_user->company;
        break;
                case 'billing_vat':
            return $current_user->vat;
        break;
    endswitch;
}, 10, 2);
```

It works except for $current_user->phone, $current_user->company, $current_user->vat

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

The phone, company and other information is in the Meta data.

```
 $phone = get_user_meta($current_user,'phone_number',true);
```

You also do not need to have a global variable. It is also dangerous.

```
 add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_get_value', function($input, $key ) 
    {
     $current_user = get_current_user_id();

    switch ($key) :
    case 'billing_first_name':
    case 'shipping_first_name':
        return $current_user->first_name;
    break;
    case 'billing_last_name':
    case 'shipping_last_name':
        return $current_user->last_name;

    case 'billing_phone':
        $phone = get_user_meta($current_user,'phone_number',true);
        return  $phone;
    break;

    case 'billing_company':
    case 'shipping_company':
         // May or may not be in meta data
    break;

   case 'billing_vat':
       // Not available through user
    break;
   endswitch;
   }, 10, 2);
```

You can see more here:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta

Vat is a bit more complicated in that it is based on country and not the user name. While country is there, the VAT will not be.  The best way to retrieve that is through woocommerce.

As for company name (sometimes called organization) that too is not direct Wordpress. It is typically added via a 3rd party plugin, like woocommerce, memberships or a custom plugin that will add the feature to the account.  You have to see what you are using.

Answer (score -1):

just use like this

global $current_user;

case 'billing_phone':
       return $current_user->billing_phone;
    break;

Comment: Please add some explanation so other can understand ! And if possible add your tried code.

Comment: Hi, you don't want to use the  $phone = get_user_meta($current_user,'phone_number',true);
        return  $phone; instead of that just use my above on that is working fine.